# Python Requests - POST not returning expected Response

Tags: python, python-requests, sql-injection

I am running the following test againt this page: 
https://www.hackthissite.org/missions/realistic/4/ . 
On that page there is an email edit box that takes in an email address.
The intent of this test is to pass in a sql string and see what happens:

```
def test_SQL_Inj_01(self):
        url = self.url + '/missions/realistic/4/addemail.php'
        payload = {'email': "'or1=1--"}
        headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
        # make request:
        print(url)
        POST_req = requests.post(url, data=payload, headers=headers)
        print(POST_req.content)
```

When I run this test it makes the Request but with the expected response code of 200, however the response body is what has me confused. 
I am expecting the response to only contain "Error inserting into table "email"! Email not valid! Please contact an administrator of Fischer's". What gets returned is a generic blob of HTML from the site I am testing against. 
When I inspect the traffic in chrome I can see that a POST is made to the "addemail.php" endpoint, so I believe I am using the correct Request type. 
I want to be able to assert that when I pass in this string that the expected error response comes back.

Comment: Why don't you use selenium?

Comment: What data format is the response supposed to be ?
have you tried `print(POST_req.json())`